# Office Templates in SharePoint 2010 Document Library

Tags: document-library

I have created a site in SharePoint 2010 named Templates.

The point of this site is to have templates stored in the document library

### and linking to the templates with URL's from a blank page.. Example:

- Letter Template
- Interview Template
- Description Template

---

When the user click on the link the document should open and the user can fill in
the blank fields. But here's the problem:

Even though the library has read only permission for the users, they are somehow able to save directly back to the library. We want to block them from saving over the template. Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 0):

Best practices would be to make the templates... well, *templates*.

Start in the advanced settings of the library, set up different content types for each template, and then your templates are protected from edits. Here's some reading to get you going: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/set-up-a-template-for-a-library-HA010024280.aspx

Comment: I know about the templates and how to build them up with content types, but this will not solve the main issue with saving against the document library? Correct me if I am wrong, but if I make a template with content type will this not autosave to the library the template is started from?

Comment: It will be saved to that library, but it will save as a _new item_ in that library. The template will remain untouched.

Comment: But this is exactly what I am trying to avoid. That is why I am asking for a solution to pick a template from the intranet and FORCE the user to save it locally and not to a library.